# app not installed when I released a new version of android app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, signing

I released a new version of android app but my signingConfigs changed and when users install new update ther get error app not installed 
how to fix it 
please help me

Comment: there is no way to fix it. They have either to uninstall the old app manually and install new one, or to keep the old one without updating

Comment: Are you sure? @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: yes, if I was not I did not write the comment.

Comment: i didnt change keyAlias , keyPassword,   storePassword i just change storefile it doesnt help? @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: it won't work if you have created another keystore, as it is created with the certificate, which is generated during creation. 2 different keystores will have different certificates.

Comment: thanks for your patient but i have other question when i create a keystore by command i saved it on drive c on my pc  i should move it to project file to save it secure,  is that corret?

Comment: you should save it secure somewhere, that is for sure. But it's up to you how to do that. I for example add it to VCS (GIT) among other project files

Comment: thanks a lot @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 1):

You can not change signingConfigs if you change that OS wouldn't allow to upgrade app and because your application id is same OS can not install this version.

You have 2 options

**1** restore you signingConfigs and release new version with that signingConfigs

**2** ask your user to uninstall previous version and install new version

Read more from [app-signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: how can i restore my signconfig i install new windows and my key file was drive c so i cant restore it

Comment: it's so bad. sorry for that but you must use 2 options and keep in mind store keys in safe place and have backup.